# Using ArduCam library for Ov7076 camera

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I am using [OmniVision OV7076 camera (without FIFO)](https://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf) with Arduino Uno.
[image: Camera]
So I want to use Github code provided in [ArduCAM repository](http://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino). They have provided [OV7076 FIFO version](http://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/OV7670FIFO) straightaway but it is using more memory.

I have used computer nerd code (provided in this tutorial [Instructables OV7076 camera](http://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/)) and the camera had worked.

But I want to use the ArduCAM repository. It would be nice if any one could provided link for the guide or can give a little walk-through.

In the ArduCAM repository, they have make an ArduCAM class which have many methods. Thus we get rid of initialisation provided in [computernerd](http://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/) code.

I want to use functions of the class directly. But i am unable to understand which method can be used for ov7076 camera. If you could write a starter code it would be very helpful.

Comment: [1]: https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino
  [2]: http://(https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/OV7670FIFO)
  [3]: http://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/

Comment: I'm not able to add them in the question :(

Comment: I'll fix it up. For future reference there is a question mark in a gray circle in the top right-hand of the edit form - this will provide you with help.

Comment: I don't have much reputation that's why i'm unable to add the links. Thanks for your efforts. :D

Comment: Does this post help? http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html

Comment: According to [this page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), you should be able to post up to 2 links. I've finished editing the post, so you have your links plus more. You may be able to approve my edits.

Comment: Sorry but it is not what i want.